# exit status 1 'WIFI_AUTH_OPEN' was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, wifi

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
 
    // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(100);
 
    Serial.println("Setup done");
}
 
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("scan start");
 
    // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    Serial.println("scan done");
    if (n == 0) {
        Serial.println("no networks found");
    } else {
        Serial.print(n);
        Serial.println(" networks found");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
            Serial.print(i + 1);
            Serial.print(": ");
            Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
            Serial.print(" (");
            Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
             Serial.print(")");
            Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN)?" ":"*");
            delay(10);
        }
    }
    Serial.println("");
 
    // Wait a bit before scanning again
    delay(5000);
}
```

The error is exit status 1
'WIFI_AUTH_OPEN' was not declared in this scope

Is it something int the library?
or am I not writing it correctely?
(Some random word so it dosent say "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
")

Comment: Delete `#include <WiFi.h>`. It is not for ESP8266.

Comment: Change `WIFI_AUTH_OPEN` to `ENC_TYPE_NONE`.